# Is there any functions or api in tfserving for reloading a loaded specific version model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am using the tfserving for serving a model with specific version which can be overwrited at any time
.

```py
model_config_list {
    config {
        name: "common"
        base_path: "/var/models/common"
        model_platform: "tensorflow"
        model_version_policy {
            specific {
                versions: 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the model file(which locate at `/var/models/common/0`) updated by overwriting, the rest api `http://localhost:8501/v1/models/common/versions/0:predict`  returns the old `versions: 0` model's output, not the latest I updated.

So, is there a rpc function or rest api to reload the `versions: 0` model from file?

*Adding version num in `base_path` and dont specify `versions` in url can solve this problem, but I will not do this because some reason.*

Comment: Does this answer https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config#serving_a_specific_version_of_a_model.

Answer (score 0):

To serve a specific version of the model, rather than always transitioning to the one with the largest version number, set model_version_policy to "specific" and provide the version number you would like to serve. For example, to pin version 42 as the one to serve:

```
model_version_policy {
  specific {
    versions: 42
  }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks, We bond the versions in tfserving config with out product's version, like "product_v1" has models with version '1', But in 'product_v1' the models will keep updating.Anyway, the way of binding product version and model version is so bad, and it is difficult to be changed now.